# A equation about Lambert $W$ function

Tags: physics, lambert-w

$$(\Delta X)(\Delta P)=\frac{\hbar}{2}\exp\left[\frac{\alpha^{2n}l_{PI}^{2n}}{\hbar^{2n}}\left(\langle\hat{P}\rangle^2+(\Delta P)^2\right)^n\right]$$
I want to solve the equation to get $\Delta P$ represented by $\Delta X$ with the method of Lambert $W$ function when $\langle\hat{P}\rangle=0$. How can I do?

Comment: If $\langle\hat{P}\rangle=0$, you can simplify into $x p=h e^{a p^{2n}}$ and solve for $x$

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I failed to solve this equation.

Answer (score 0):

Tymas comment is right.
$x p=h e^{a p^{2n}}$ has solution for $p$
$$
p=\frac {h}{x} \exp\left({-{\frac {1}{2\,n}{\rm W} \left(-2\,an{{\rm e}^{
-2\,n\,\ln  \left( x/h \right)}}\right)}}\right)
$$
according to Maple.

But $x p=h e^{a (1+p)^{2n}}$ does not have solution for $p$ using $W$ (as far as Maple found).